Error while building Android 9 on ubuntu 20.04
I'm facing some problems while building firmware Android 9 for my device on Ubuntu 20.04. For more details, the build was successful on Ubuntu 18.04.
Import includes file: out/target/product/vnpt_smb_mytv/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libvhls_mod_intermediates/import_includes
target arm C: libhls <= packages/amlogic/LibPlayer/third_parts/libvhls/hls_main/hls_m3uparser.c
target arm C: libhls <= packages/amlogic/LibPlayer/third_parts/libvhls/hls_main/hls_m3ulivesession.c
target arm C: libhls <= packages/amlogic/LibPlayer/third_parts/libvhls/hls_main/hls_fifo.c
packages/amlogic/LibPlayer/third_parts/libvhls/hls_main/hls_m3uparser.c:21:26: fatal error: amthreadpool.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [out/target/product/vnpt_smb_mytv/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhls_intermediates/hls_m3uparser.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
packages/amlogic/LibPlayer/third_parts/libvhls/hls_main/hls_m3ulivesession.c:13:30: fatal error: libavformat/avio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [out/target/product/vnpt_smb_mytv/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhls_intermediates/hls_m3ulivesession.o] Error 1

Does anyone have idea to solve it? Please help, thanks.

Your error messages list two header files; are the relevant packages installed?  If not, what happens when you install them?
